# C++ - const members / return const int& vs return int

Tags: c++

What do we mean by those C++ lines? Are there alternative ways to writing them?

```
const int& a() const;
int getA() const;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

These two are two possible signatures for a member function in a class that promises not to change the object itself. In the first case it will return a constant reference to an integer (possibly a member attribute), the reference being `const` means that the caller will not be able to use it to change the internal attribute. The second case it returns an integer by value.

There are slight differences in the semantics, but in most cases they will not be important, consider them as two functions to obtain a value. For a case where it will make a difference see this:

```
class test {
public:
   test() : m_value() {
      std::cout << &m_value << std::endl; // print where the attribute is
   }
   int const & getValue() const {
      return m_value;
   }
   int copyValue() const {
      return m_value;
   }
   void setValue( int value ) {
      m_value = value;
   }
private:
   int m_value;
};
int main() {
   test t;                      // will printout an address [1]
   int v1 = t.getValue();       // caller copies the value
   int v2 = t.copyValue();      // caller copies the value (itself a copy in hte calle)
   int const &r = t.getValue(); // reference to t.m_value
   int const &c = t.copyValue();// reference to *copy* [2]
   std::cout << v1 << v2 << r << c
      << std::cout;             // 0000
   std::cout << &v1 << &v2      // 4 pointers, the third is [1] a r *is* t.m_value
      << &r << &c << std::cout; //     the rest should be different
   t.setValue( 5 );
   std::cout << v1 << v2 << r   // 0050, v1 and v2 where copies, r *is* t.m_value
      << c << std::cout;
}
```

The line marked with [2] uses a *strange* feature of the language by which if you obtain a *constant reference* to an r-value (temporary) the compiler will *bind* that temporary to the reference and keep it alive until the reference goes out of scope (basically it turns the r-value temporary into a hidden variable and binds the reference to it).

I added that line to be explicit in that the difference in behavior is not due to the receiving end `main` making a copy of maintaining a reference, but rather (*also* to be precise) by the signature of the accessor.

Answer (score 8):

Both are equivalent ways to achieve the same thing:

```
const int& a() const;
int getA() const;
```

You are returning a value. The **const** at the right of the method header is a remark that functions getA() and a() won't modify the object that will execute them (the hidden this parameter). This is important at compile time, since it means that extra verifications will be taken into account while compiling. At runtime, there is no difference between those function above and these:

```
const int& a();
int getA();
```

However, the huge benefits of extending the verification capabilities of the compiler (nothing is being changed when you don't expect it to happen) are obviously worth the *extra* **const**.

The second part to worry about are the return types for both functions, which stands for the main difference between them, and probably are the motivation of the question. Let's change the subject to a different function:

```
std::string getName() const;
   { return name; }
```

Here, the return value will probably be the name attribute from the class. The return is being made by value, which means that a copy of the attribute will be created when returning from this method. This can be an issue when the string is big and you are moving a lot of strings by value around your application. Then it happens to appear the return-by-reference mechanism, which promises no copying:

```
std::string &getName() const
   { return name; }
```

This is actually very interesting: we are returning a reference, instead of a copy of the object. A reference is similar to a pointer, so you'll have to copy only a pointer (4 bytes in a 32 bit system) instead of the whole object.
This is promising. However, it won't even compile. The compile will complain that you are returning a reference while you promised the method to be **const**, and therefore, the object it will execute over shouldn't be modified. This code would allow illegal operations to happen:

```
Person p( "Baltasar" );
p.getName() = "José";

cout << p.getName() << endl;
```

That's why the **const** for the return type appears as a new attractive, option that will solve the problem. A constant reference won't allow modifications of the object it points to, with:

```
const std::string &getName() const
    { return name; }
```

It will now compile, while the previous, malign code won't.
Now let's return to our problem:

```
const int &getA() const;
int a() const;
```

The second one is a *return-by-value*, which means that the **int** (4 bytes) will be copied on return. The first one means that a constant reference to an **int** (4 bytes) will be returned. As it can be seen, there is no performance benefit in this case for using *return-by-reference* instead of *return-by-value*.

As a rule of thumb, return by const reference is always safe, it will never be more expensive than return by value.

Comment: return by reference WILL be more expensive when the refered is small, as dereferencing will take time.

Comment: "Both are equivalent ways to achieve the same thing:"  Almost.  If you
use the return value to initialize a reference (i.e. `int const& ri
= ...;`, returning the reference means you run the risk of having
a dangling reference; returning the value doesn't.

Comment: You imply that if the reference happens to be of the same size as an `int`, then the amount of work done is equivalent, but that doesn't factor in the client's effort to follow the reference and read the value....

Comment: Thank to your comments. @tony, @flownt, the cost of copying and referencing a small value can be comparable in my opinion. @Kanze, the only way to get adangling reference is (by its own nature) to return a reference to a local variable in the method, while here we are dealing with an attribute. On the other hand, the compiler will warn you if you try to return a reference to a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
const int& a() const;
```

`a()` returns a const reference to an `int`. `const` modifier at the end signifies that it cannot change the state of the object it is called up on.

```
int getA() const;
```

Same as the above description except that the return type is `int` which involves a copy of the returned variable if collected.

**What is meant when said cannot change the state of object?**

```
class foo
{
    int m_Var ;
    public:
        foo(int arg1) : m_Var(arg1){}
        void mutableMethod()
        {
            m_Var = 20 ;  // "this" has the variable m_Var and
                          //  by assigning it a value changes the state of
                          //  m_Var. Changing the state of it's member variable
                          //  is meant changing the state of object.
        }

        void nonMutableMethod() const
        {
             m_Var = 20 ;  //  This assignment is not allowed because of const 
                           //  modifier. The method is not allowed to change the
                           //  the state of object on which it is called ( this )
        }
};
```

Also, constant methods cannot return member variables by non-const reference.

Comment: a() returns a const reference `to a int`. I believe its also worthwhile to mention about `mutable members`.cannot change the state of the object it is called upon with the exception of mutable members.

Comment: @Als: there's `const_cast` too ;-)

Comment: @Tony: I was just about to edit to add that but Well spotted ;) I think its worthwhile to mention those for a complete understanding of `const`.

Answer (score 2):

The crucial difference is that:

- `getA()` returns an `int` data value which can then be used by the caller completely independent of any other part of the program
- `a()` returns a reference to some `int` that `a()` selects:

  - `int x = a()` "samples" the int value at that time, and is logically equivalent to `int x = getA()`
  - `const int& x = a()` **saves a reference to the variable returned by a()**!

*Saving references doesn't always do what you expect or want*

- the GOOD: the compiler is smart enough to make a copy of that variable if it was a temporary / literal (e.g. `const int& x = a()`, `const int& a() { return 3; }`)
- the GOOD or **BAD?** (depending on whether it makes sense in the app): each time the value of `x` is read later, the program may (attempt to) reread it from the original `int` variable that `a()` internally returned: if that variable's value has since changed, then the value of `x` will also change.  ("may" because the optimiser can avoid this when the value would be the same anyway)
- the **UGLY**: if the memory at that address is no longer storing that variable (e.g. it was in `new`ed memory that's since been `delete`d), then trying to read the value of `x` may result in an *unpredictable value* or *crash the application* (if the memory address is no longer readable).

Both `a()` and `getA()` are member functions of a class; we know this because only member functions can be `const`, which technically indicates they can't change non-`mutable` data members without casting away their constness, but the intent behind that restriction is that they shouldn't modify the caller-observable value of an object; mutable data is normally for caching, debug trace etc..

Answer (score 0):

We can cast returned reference to pointer, so theoretically it makes more info available (address and value) than returning a copy (value).

And it's possible to hack const ref to mutable with const_cast.

Compiler will try to use value from original register, address or literal anyway.

Alternative ways for which goal? To make sure that staying constantly correct wouldn't add extra work. For const reference and const I find CR & CN macros handy.

```
#define CN  const
#define CR  const&         // Constant reference
#define CDa const*         // mutable pointer to constant data
#define CPD const * const  // constant pointer to constant data
const int&  verbose() const;
int CR      shorter() CN;
```

Side-effect is that declarations get shorter and as lines get shorter, the number of lines also decreases. Matter of taste tho... But when combined with DMAP macro, it seems to have an advantage.

```
typedef std::map<size_t, float>     TypeMap_Of_size_t_vs_float;
TypeMap_Of_size_t_vs_float          m_Map;
const TypeMap_Of_size_t_vs_float&   verboseIsNice() const
{
    return m_MyMap;
}
for each (auto myElement in verboseIsNice()) 
{
    myElement.foo();
}
```

vs

```
DMAP(SZ, Flo)  m_Map;                    // typedefs MSZFlo=std::map<size_t, float>
MSZFlo CR      tldr()                 CN { return m_Map; }
fe(el, tldr()) el.foo();
```

*Without auto and with using iterators the example would show more than 333% of difference.*